# Pandas: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

```
import pandas

readdata = pandas.read_csv("/home/Projects/test1.csv")

for i in range (1,4):
    for line in readdata:
        if readdata.irow(0) + i == readdata.irow(1):
            print readdata
```

I'm using python 2.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/PycharmProjects/filters.py", line 8, in <module>
    if readdata.irow(0) + i == readdata.irow(1):
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 714, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I insist on using pandas if possible because it offers many things I want to work with. if not possible then I know how to do it in csv module, I changed the code in order to use pandas, but it's the first time so it's tricky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unclear from your code what you're trying to do.

`readdata` is *all* the data in the csv file. You seem to want to iterate over that data (maybe you want to iterate over the rows?), so you start to do that, but then you call functions on `readdata` that give you whole rows of values at once.

Let's play interactively with pandas. I have created a test csv file:

```
"x","y"
1,3
2,6
3,9
4,10
```

Now, in python:

```
Python 2.7.10 (v2.7.10:15c95b7d81dc, May 23 2015, 09:33:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
>>> readdata = pandas.read_csv("/tmp/test1.csv")
```

You have that. Now let's look at what `readdata` is:

```
>>> readdata
   x   y
0  1   3
1  2   6
2  3   9
3  4  10
```

Okay, so that reads the data. But what happens when you try to iterate over it?

```
>>> for line in readdata:
...     print repr(line)
... 
'x'
'y'
```

Oh no! Iterating over just `readdata` gives me the column names. Well that's clearly not what you want. Poking around shows me that there's a `.iterrows()` method on `readdata`, so let's try that:

```
>>> for (linenum, line) in readdata.iterrows():
...   print line.irow(0)
... 
1
2
3
4
```

Well that's better. So will this do what you want?

```
import pandas

readdata = pandas.read_csv("/home/Projects/test1.csv")

for i in range (1,4):
    for (linenum, line) in readdata.iterrows():
        if line.irow(0) + i == line.irow(1):
            print line
```

Now it's time to dive into the docs to figure out more about how to format pandas series objects to get the output the way you want. As a hint, using this (after putting `import sys` at the top of the script) instead of `print line` might be what you want:

```
            pandas.DataFrame([line]).to_csv(sys.stdout, index=False, header=False)
```

Once you're ready for more advanced pandas usage:

```
import pandas
import sys

readdata = pandas.read_csv("/home/Projects/test1.csv", header=None)

for i in range (1,4):
  readdata[readdata.icol(0) + i == readdata.icol(1)].to_csv(sys.stdout, index=False, header=False)
```

Or, if you want separate files:

```
import pandas

readdata = pandas.read_csv("/home/Projects/test1.csv", header=None)

for i in range (1,4):
  with open("/home/Projects/test1.out.%d.csv" % i, "w") as f:
    readdata[readdata.icol(0) + i == readdata.icol(1)].to_csv(f, index=False, header=False)
```

That uses array operations to grab whole large slices of the data at once.

The basic key to making stuff using pandas faster is to replace loops done iteratively in python with array operations. But if this usage is at all a surprise, you really need to stop and work through one or more pandas tutorials.

Comment: Note that doing things this way is likely much slower than necessary, and a real `pandas` expert would show you how to use bulk array operations to find all the rows with one column equal to the other `+ i` in a single statement without the iteration over rows. However, that's for after you've gotten your feet wet.

Comment: Your code sir skips the first row and start printing from the second one, but thats alright, I added `header=None`

Comment: whats the fastest way? i'm working with 5 million rows so i need all the speed i can get and btw the way I tackled the problem is wrong, shouldve been workiing with columns, i don't know what I was thinking, I deserve the downvotes...

Comment: 5 million isn't what I'd call really large enough to be too concerned with speed, but I updated the answer to show you how to use array operations to select the data you wanted.